# How to specify public and private keys in env file

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

Currently, I have public and private `.pem` files that I import into my Express app. How can I provide those in my env files? Since the keys span multiple lines, I'm unable to import from env properly. I guess it's a question on how to import keys from env so that in the end I just have to do `process.env.pub_key`.

Comment: How are you setting/getting your env vars now? Are you using a `.env` file? If so, you can use something like the `dotenv` package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @bherbruck yup using env file and using `dotenv` package to retrieve env variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `.env` fil to manage your environment variables, I would use the `dotenv` package and then export your variables from a config file.

.env

```
PUB_KEY_PATH="./keys/public.pub/rsa-abc-123-lmnop"
SOME_OTHER_ENV_VAR="some-other-value"
```

config.js/ts

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()
export const PUB_KEY_PATH = process.env.PUB_KEY_PATH
```

usage

```
import { PUB_KEY_PATH } from './config'

console.log(PUB_KEY_PATH)
```

Comment: I did that but for builds on the cloud how would that work? I can't upload the private keys on GitHub surely

Comment: Which cloud platform? Many paas services (like heroku) let you do that from their cli/web app. If it is a hosted vps you will need to do it a different way.